# Default selectors and acceptors in Jetty ServerConnector

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, nio

According to the official [documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html), the default number of selectors is equal to the number of cores available.

> The default number of selectors is equal to the number of processors available to the JVM, which should allow optimal performance even if all the connections used are performing significant non-blocking work in the callback tasks.

However, looking at the code, the default number of selectors appears to be half the number of available cores

```
public ServerConnector(
    @Name("server") Server server,
    @Name("executor") Executor executor,
    @Name("scheduler") Scheduler scheduler,
    @Name("bufferPool") ByteBufferPool bufferPool,
    @Name("acceptors") int acceptors,
    @Name("selectors") int selectors,
    @Name("factories") ConnectionFactory... factories)
{
    super(server,executor,scheduler,bufferPool,acceptors,factories);
    _manager = newSelectorManager(getExecutor(), getScheduler(),
        selectors>0?selectors:Math.max(1,Math.min(4,Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()/2)));
    addBean(_manager, true);
    setAcceptorPriorityDelta(-2);
}
```

There's a similar discrepancy in number of acceptors. The documentation state

> The default number of acceptor tasks is the minimum of 1 and half the number of available CPUs. Having more acceptors may reduce the latency for servers that see a high rate of new connections (eg HTTP/1.0 without keep-alive).  Typically the default is sufficient for modern persistent protocols (HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2 etc.)

But the code says otherwise

```
    if (acceptors < 0)
        acceptors=Math.max(1, Math.min(4,cores/8));
```

Is this to handle `hyperthreading` or is there some other reason? Even if this was to account for `hyperthreading`,  the number of acceptors should have been `cores / 4`. Can someone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like out of date docs. (it used to be the documentation way, but the advent of large core CPUs and JVM limits made it necessary to change this behavior)

Comment: I've opened an issue to have this documentation updated: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1426